# In Rails Migration, how can I handle multidatabases

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I want to work with more than one database in rails how can I handles separate migration one for each database?

In this case I have one account database and other database for the data.

Having something like:

migrate/accounts/*.*
migrate/mydatabase/*.*

So I can run independents migrations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your database.yml create the different connections to the database like:

```
development1:
  adapter: mysql
  username: root
  password: 
  database: example_development1

development2:
  adapter: mysql
  username: root
  password: 
  database: example_development2
```

Then to each model you choose to each database it is stored using:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base  
 establish_connection :development2
end
```

EDIT
If you want to apply it to a migration you can do:

```
class Migration1 < ActiveRecord::Migration 
  def self.connection 
    Account.connection #being Account a model that has a connection to the database you want 
  end 
 .....
end
```

Comment: This is a great answer, this also apply to migration?